# what is the difference using the function $ X {} in ireport 2.0.2 and 4.1.1

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i want to ask about the list. How to using formula $X{} in iReport 2.0.2. Can you show me an example so that i know that function.

update Question:-
what is the difference using the function $ X {} in ireport ireport 2.0.2 and 4.1.1. Why ireport 2.0.2 can not read the data field but ireport 4.1.1 can read the data?. Are there any examples to correct the list of situations like this.[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a specific question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957034/list-as-subreport-parameter

Comment: i have problem to read the field in ireport 2.0.2 when i using the $X{}. why it's to be like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this bug report: http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mantis/view.php?id=4301

Answer (score 1):

I prompt my user to provide the name of a pharmacy (parameter is a Collection) and then I feed it into my query's where clause like so:

WHERE $X{IN, PHAR_CODE, pharmacy}

In my database, the pharmacy identifier can be found in a field called PHAR_CODE, and the name of the parameter supplied by the user is pharmacy. A user could query on one or more pharmacies, so I am using $X. Using the default value supplies information on all pharmacies.

Comment: i have try your way but it can't read the field. Why it's to be like that?.Can you show me the full example? because im using ireport 2.0.2.